# Scraping multiple tags on single page using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to automate one website using Excel VBA to do get data from multi-tab on a singe page. But it is only giving the information which is on the first tab I am not getting any object from the second tab.

I am using below code:

```vb
Sub BrowseToSite()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput, link As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButtons, links, FButtons, Export As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "URL"
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document
    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
        Debug.Print HTMLButton.tagName, HTMLButton.innerText
    Next

End Sub
```

Whenever I click `Incident Queue`, it opens up a new tab every time, and I want to click on `Company` link from 2nd tab. I don't have much detail as there is a secure site so even share the URL will not work. All I want to do is populate the element from the next tab. Most of them are links.

Here is the image of the web page:

[image: page]

The web page HTML content before `Incident Queue` click https://uploadfiles.io/wdx0h, and after click https://uploadfiles.io/l85uv.

Comment: Please share more details. What is the webpage URL or HTML content of the entire webpage? What data you need to retrieve, and what is the expected output?

Comment: Perhaps when you click the tab on the page the inner html is added by an event, or the page might be reloaded if its php. Try clicking the tab then reading its contents.

Comment: @omegastripes,@ClintB: Please help

Comment: Seems HTML files you shared don't contain `Incident Queue` node, which is located on the left part of the page. Does the page consist of several frames?

Comment: Try to examine XHRs which are logged on network tab in browser's developer tools, right after you click on `Incident Queue`.